# Trying to save null value with arcObjects

Tags: c#, esri, dbnull, arcobjects

I'm trying to save a null in an integer column with arcObjects but it always save 0 when the value is null.
Can anyone explain me what is happening?
I am developing in C#.

I tried to assign DBNull.Value to my variable but I can't because it's an integer.
Thank you very much for your time and your knowledge!

Visual Studio side:

[image]

[image: Visual Studio Side]

ArcGIS side:

[image: ArcGis Side]

Comment: `int` being a value type it will have a value defaulted to 0. Why don't you use nullable int [`int?`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx) instead?

Comment: I tried it. When type is int?, I set null for the variable and it records 0 on DB, not null

Comment: Could you please share the relevant code, so that we could take a look?

Comment: I wish the edit helps. thank you for your time L J

Answer (score 2):

U need DBNull

```
... = (entry.Value == null) ? DBNull.Value : entry.Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved!!

Setting DBNull in this point the problem dissapear:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Shapefile does not support Null in field value and converts it to default value ie 0 for integer types. In a Geodatabase, the field "Allow NULL values" property should be set to "Yes".